# What library does Facebook use for dismiss image by dragging?

Tags: android, facebook, image, gesture, dismiss

i feel curious what library is used for dismiss an image by swipe up or down which facebook or the others app are using? It's awesome gesture but i couldn't find any suggestion for it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I think Facebook developer team can build their own swipe layout without using external libraries since they are great and talented engineers, but here's is one library provided similar functionality.
[SwipeBackLayout](https://github.com/ikew0ng/SwipeBackLayout)

Comment: Thank for your answer :) I will try your lib for my purpose